# SwiftでCFStringNormalizeをすると落ちてしまいます

Tags: swift

swiftでデータベースの検索画面を作成しています。
UISearchBarで入力したテキストからFMDBのクエリを作成して渡しています。
その際、データベースの中に入っている文字コードがUTF-8-MACなので、以下のような関数を作り、一旦UISearchBarのテキストを変換しています。

```
func textChange(SearchBartext:NSString)->NSString{
  var bbbb:NSMutableString = SearchBartext as NSString as NSMutableString
  CFStringNormalize(bbbb, .D)
  return bbbb
}
```

こうすることでデータベースでもきちんと検索がかかるのですが、ARCがメモリ解放するタイミングでEXC_BAD_ACCESEで落ちてしまうのです。
分からないのは、おそらくこの変換で影響がないであろう文字がSearchBartextに入った時にはEXC_BAD_ACCESEにならないことなのです。
濁点・半濁点などが入ると落ちてしまいますが、それ以外のひらがなやカタカナなどでは普通に動くのです。

ご教授願います。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSString`はimmutableなので書き換えてはいけません。
`mutableCopy`を使って`NSMutableString`のコピーを作成してください。

```
func textChange(SearchBartext:NSString)->NSString{
  var bbbb:NSMutableString = SearchBartext.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableString
  CFStringNormalize(bbbb, .D)
  return bbbb
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。無事に動きました。
型まわりの勉強不足でした。コンパイラがエラーを出さないからといって、適当に書いてはいけませんね。精進します。